# ion-item cuts off an absolute positioned element

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

`ion-item` cuts off an image that i have absolutely positioned. putting ion-item overflow on auto has brought nothing...

**Example**

[image]

**Code**

```
<ion-item-sliding class="itemBooksContainer" #slidingBooks>
        <ion-item item-wrap class="itemBooks">
          <ion-icon ios="ios-paper" md="md-paper" item-start></ion-icon>
          <strong>{{ "STATISTICS.books" | translate }}</strong>
          <strong item-end>{{ currentMonthDataBooks }}</strong>
          <span class="swipeHand" *ngIf="showFinger">
            <img height="100" src="../../assets/img/swipeHand.png" alt="Swipe">
          </span>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options side="left">
          <button ion-button color="danger" icon-only (click)="substractBooks()"><ion-icon ios="ios-remove" md="md-remove"></ion-icon></button>
          <button ion-button color="light">{{ currentMonthDataBooks }}</button>
        </ion-item-options>
        <ion-item-options side="right">
          <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addBooks()"><ion-icon ios="ios-add" md="md-add"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-item-options>
      </ion-item-sliding>
```

The hand should be completely visible..... :-) What´s the problem?

Comment: Try `overflow:visible`?

Comment: Tried already - does not work... maybe a problem with display: flex?

Comment: You'll have to inspect the DOM. There's probably some z-index trickery going on for the swipe action.

Comment: I really don't find anything here at all :/ No z-index instructions, nothing...

Answer (score 2):

The solution was set `contain: unset;` on ion-item! Not it works :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was `position: flex;` that I had to change to `position: absolute;`